# send get request with angular to Origin http://localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js, cross-domain

I am Newbie to angular js. Here I am trying to call API from rails server with "http://localhost:3000/". I got error for

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

I have added 'CORS' chrome extension to fix it. Now the problem is my request is passing to localhost:3000 as [OPTIONS], and **I want it as get request**.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('dayton')
.service('foodCategoryService', ['$http', '$window', 'authService', 'Upload',
  function($http, $window, authService, Upload){
        var field = {};

      field.getFields = function (){
        console.log("---------foodCategoryService")
        return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/list_food_category',  {
          headers: {Authorization: authService.getToken()}
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          return response;
        }, function(x) {
          $scope.authError = 'Server Error';
        });
      };
        return field;
  }]);
```

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS]
>   "/api/list_food_category"):

Any help is going to be appreciated

Comment: CORS plugin only can't fix it. Your server needs to allow request for CORS.

Comment: You don't need a CORS extension, if you are making calls and hosting your frontend on the same host, ie `localhost` right?

Comment: No, I am using two different servers here. http://localhost:8081/ is my current server and I am trying to send api call to http://localhost:3000/

Comment: @Ved I have tried to add  allow request for CORS. would you suggest me any link to refer ? I have tried  with app.use(function (req, res, next) { .... but getting error for app and use function in express.js

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors

Answer (score 0):

modify your app config

```
angular.module('dayton').config(function($httpProvider){

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, In while file do I need to add this ?

Comment: in your controller file

Comment: I have added this lines in foodCategoryController.js . But same issue I got. request is passing as [OPTIONS] . not as get request.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your angular js side problem. You have to allow cross origin request at your server end

Comment: For server side, I am using node.js . Can you please suggest which changes I need to do for that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Ac
cess_control_CORS

example code : 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});